# System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

Tenho que converter um datatable para XML. Meu datatable tem 68256 linhas.

Quando faço a serialização para XML, recebo o erro OutOfMemoryException: Exception_WasThrown.

Segue o código que estou utilizando para fazer a conversão :

```
 var ds = new DataSet();
 dtDados.TableName = "result";

 ds.Tables.Add(dtDados);

 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
   using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
   {
     var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
     xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, ds);
     var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

     return xml;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Está carregando algo grande demais para a memória disponível.

Comment: tentou usar o `.GetXml();` ?  `DataSet ds = new DataSet();  ds.GetXml();`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis mesmo erro.

Comment: a não ser que sejam textos muito grandes, ou arquivos/imagens, 68k linhas é muito pouco, como bigown falou, está faltando memória. infelizmente não sei como te ajudar. Talvez dividir esses dados